# getting column divs side-by-side

Tags: html, css

I have a div block that looks like this.

```
<div id="wrap">
       <div id="columns" class="columns_4">
         <figure>
           <a href="item.php?id={$row['product_id']}"><img src="../resources/{$product_image}" alt="">
           <figcaption>{$row['product_description']}</figcaption>
           <span class="price">&#163;{$row['product_price']}</span>
           <a class="button" href="../resources/cart.php?add={$row['product_id']}">Add to Cart</a>
         </figure>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Despite using `display: inline-block;` in the `CSS`, the divs are still cascading down the page as opposed to sitting  side by side (which is what I am trying to acheive).

[image]

Where might I be going wrong in this approach.

> CSS

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  min-height: 1000px;
}

#wrap{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.columns_2 figure{
   width:49%;
   margin-right:1%;
}
.columns_2 figure:nth-child(2){
    margin-right: 0;
}
.columns_3 figure{
   width:32%;
   margin-right:1%;
}
.columns_3 figure:nth-child(3){
    margin-right: 0;
}
.columns_4 figure{
   width:24%;
   margin-right:1%;
}
.columns_4 figure:nth-child(4){
    margin-right: 0;
}
.columns_5 figure{
   width:19%;
   margin-right:1%;
}
.columns_5 figure:nth-child(5){
    margin-right: 0;
}
#columns figure:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);

}
#columns:hover figure:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
div#columns figure {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FEFEFE;
    border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    margin: 0 0px 15px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

div#columns figure img {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

div#columns figure figcaption {
  font-size: .9rem;
  color: #444;
  line-height: 1.5;
  height:60px;
  font-weight:600;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

a.button{
  padding:10px;
  background:salmon;
  margin:10px;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  transition:all 1s linear;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius:3px;
  border-bottom:3px solid #ff6536;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
a.button:hover{
  background:#ff6536;
  border-bottom:3px solid salmon;
  color:#f1f2f3;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) { 
  #columns figure { width: 24%; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #columns figure { width:32%;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #columns figure { width: 49%;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #columns figure { width: 100%;}
}

[![screenshot][2]][2]
```

Comment: Use `display:flex` to `wrap`

Comment: The only thing you made inline-block, is the figure element inside this construct. So if you repeat the whole construct multiple times(?), the outer div of course still is a block level element.

Comment: Looks quite normal [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBQPbN). Maybe something else is causing this? I assume the `figure` is the repeating element, not the wrapping `div`.

Comment: I will try the approaches presented. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on how you create multiple element:

- if you use your "columns" as container
  than add `float:left;` to `div#columns figure`
  [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/01re2va4/5/)
- if you use your "wrap" as container it you need to add `float:left;` to `#wrap` **but** your % width prevent the "side-by-side" view. so you need to define somewhere a fixed size width ( like body, html or simple #column ) and set the wrap size to 100% ( or 90% if you want ). [Working](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgxhyke9/4/)

Comment: that worked, thank you very much, just added float:left; to div#columns figure

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
#columns {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: that didn't seem to work, appreciate the recommendation thought

Answer (score 0):

As @Chan MT says, it properly works [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBQPbN) (his codepen).

Use your **web inspector** and check for `div` widths, that may cause the problem. I guess that as your page is bigger than what you gave, there is more CSS which may cause the cascading.

Indeed, share an screenshot about it so we can see if it's because of any div.

You can also check [this codepen](https://codepen.io/luismiguelss/pen/OwQyzW) with less "products" so you can see it's not a matter of quantity.